# Wordpress - Best practice for pushing updates to multiple servers using version control

Tags: wordpress, git, version-control

So I am about to add another WP blog, but I'd like to keep it under version control. Then I started thinking, how would that affect my current WP workflow. Based on my limited xp in using WP, when an update is pushed from WP dev team, I see an indication in my admin control panel. From here I can simply click the button, and the changes are implemented behind the scene. This approach is great for a single WP instance outside of version control, but what about more nodes, and in version control?

Some of the WP updates include both code and schema changes, so I can't simply publish the code without also implementing the new schema changes. The best I can figure it is to do the following:

1. Localize current WP version stored in version control
2. Download latest (stable) wp files
3. Extract to local path (created in step 1)
4. Diff changes (optional)
5. Commit changes to version control
6. Log into each server
7. Put into maintenance mode
8. Pull latest changes
9. Implement new schema changes (????)
10. Test
11. Take out of maintenance mode

Step 9 is what is tripping me up. Do I do a schema dump from my local (freshly updated) schema, then import that schema for every server (or use provided schema change file if WP included id).

Is there a better approach to this?

---- EDIT 1.20.2014 ----

After further consideration, I wonder if setting up some type of mysql replication would be the way to go? Have one node access with read/write access so it can make changes which are restricted to database only (i.e. de-activating a widget), but have other servers serving up the blog content read from readonly mysql instances which are replicated to. This way only one server is making changes from which the others will pull. During my research I have noticed that some changes like alterations to child theme via functions.php or style.css can be tracked in version control, but other changes like activating/de-activating widgets are purely sql based, which would be impossible to track in version control.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better approach to this?

- Don't touch WP core (do you **really need it**?)

OR

- Hack core only once in order to **replace default repository's URL** of WP-core with *your's* and later use system auto-updater with your repository

Comment: I'm not touching core, if I need to add functionality, I try to do so through the editor. What I'm wondering is if I add a new theme to my dev branch, how do I get the changes to the production machine. As adding a new theme also includes data insertion into the database, but the resultsets between dev and production will different and I don't want to purge out data on production.

Comment: @MikePurcell - properly written theme (or plugin) doesn't require changing schema by hand (it's bad idea in any case) and must be installed for the first time using default WP-way. For updating later - read [WordPress Self-Hosted Plugin Update API](http://clark-technet.com/2010/12/wordpress-self-hosted-plugin-update-api)

Comment: So are you suggesting to do intial dev, push to prod. Then in prod use the self-updater feature, never dealing with the dev version again?

Comment: @MikePurcell - no, install your plugin|theme using **default way**, read readme of auto-updater on Github and follow instructions from it